# Отличие JPA и Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Чем JPA отличается от Hibernate?
JPA - спецификация.
Hibernate - реализация JPA + свои особенности.
Использование срецификации позволяет удобно менять одну реализацию на другую. Где это используется и когда это может быть удобно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на Ваш вопрос. JPA это спецификация, а Hibernate - это ORM фреймворк/библиотека, которая совместима с JPA. Как и в классическом ООП, класс, который реализует интерфейс, может иметь дополнительные методы/свойства, так и Hiberante имеет больше фичей чем JPA. По некоторым данным, сама спецификация JPA была создана на базе идей, воплощенных в Hibernate, тем не менее, официальной реализацией является EclipseLink.

> Когда удобно менять реализацию и для чего это нужно?

Поменять реализацию может потребоваться, например, в следующих случаях:

- Существенные недостатки (баги) в используемой реализации или ее версии
- Изменения в лицензировании вашего продукта (Hibernate имеет больше ограничений по сравнению с EclipseLink).
- Переход на использование другого сервера приложений. Большинство EE-серверов имеют встроенную реализацию JPA. И часто имеет смысл использовать то, что поставляется с сервером приложений, чтобы избежать проблем с совместимостью.
- Специфические требования к ORM

Answer (score 2):

JPA - это танец, Hibernate это танцор.

> JPA is the Art, Hibernate is the artist

..