# JPA & HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Здравствуйте скажите пожалуйста в чем разница между JPA и HIBERNATE и если не сложно скажите что такое HIBERNATE и что такое JPA

Comment: ну вроде [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) нормально написана для общего обозрения

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие JPA и Hibernate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556989/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-jpa-%d0%b8-hibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA - это стандарт ORM, а Hibernate - это одна из его реализаций.

**UPDATE:**

Постараюсь как можно более просто. Для начала о том, что такое ORM. Данные в реляционных базах хранятся в таблицах.

```
 id | name | age
-----------------
  1 | Jack | 24
  2 | John | 31
```

Если отбросить нюансы, то при выборке этих данных из базы в программу с помощью JDBC получается двумерный "массив" - массив строк таблицы, каждая из которых представляет массив колонок таблицы. Неудобная для работы структура. Java-программистам намного удобнее работать с объектами.

```
class Person {
    long id;
    String name;
    int age;

    // Модификаторы доступа, конструкторы
    // и аксессоры опущены для краткости
}
```

Поэтому программист напишет код, который обойдёт в цикле массив строк, на каждой итерации создаст объект, присвоит полям объекта значения из массива колонок и вернёт их все в виде списка.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/somedatabase",
                                              "someuser",
                                              "somepassword");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id, name, age from persons");
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
    person.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    person.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
    persons.add(person);
}
rs.close();
conn.close();
```

Это называется *mapping*. Но, во-первых, у всех таблиц разная структура и надо под каждую писать маппер, во-вторых, надо писать запросы в базу на языке SQL, в-третьих, надо самому создавать структуру таблиц. А если на каком-то из этих этапов запутался, компилятор не заметит и программа упадёт при выполнении. К тому же, надо ведь данные ещё и обратно в базу сохранять, извлекать данные из объекта, формировать запрос, выполнять его. Неудобно. Вот бы просто описать класс, а потом запустить какой-нибудь универсальный маппер, чтобы он сам создал таблицу под этот класс и сам конвертировал данные между таблицей и объектами. Такой универсальный маппер и есть ORM.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonUnit");
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
List<Person> persons = entityManager.createQuery("from Person", Person.class)
                                    .getResultList();
```

Чтобы объяснить разницу между стандартом JPA и его реализацией Hibernate прибегну к аналогиям. Стандарт - это схема, описывающая общие принципы работы. Например, схема грузовика описывает, что у грузовика должны быть колёса, кабина, кузов, двигатель, вращение руля должно поворачивать колёса, а нажатие на педаль тормоза останавливать грузовик. Реализация - это конкретное решение выполненное по схеме - ЗИЛ-131, Камаз-43501 и т.п. Преимущество реализации выполненной по стандарту в том, что программист/водитель может легко сменить одну реализацию/грузовик на другую, не тратя время и силы на переобучение.

На сегодняшний день JPA реализуют Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA и DataNucleus. Широко применяются первые два, а эталонной реализацией считается Hibernate.

Comment: если не сложно можно более подробнее

Comment: @Hovhannisyan JPA - это набор интерфейсов, например EntityManager, с которыми Вы и будете работать в Вашей программе. Hibernate - это набор классов, которые реализуют JPA интерфейсы.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

JPA - это танец, а Hibernate - танцор

JPA - это спецификация для доступа, хранения и управления данными между объектами Java и реляционной базой данных. Поскольку определение говорит о его API, это только спецификация. Для API нет реализации. JPA определяет набор правил и рекомендаций для разработки интерфейсов, которые следуют стандарту. Прямо к сути: JPA - это всего лишь руководство по реализации реляционного сопоставления объектов (ORM), и для реализации не существует базового кода. Где, как, Hibernate - это фактическая реализация руководящих принципов JPA.