# JPA SPECIFICATION

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Поясните плз.. Есть JPA спецификация, стандарт который описывает работу с ORM.. Доя того что бы использовать его нужна реализация которая предоставлена разными вендорами в том числе Хибернэйт. Вопросы: что в себя включает спецификация JPA только документ или ещё интерфейсы, классы? Почему различают 2 понятия - строить приложении в соответствии с JPA и строить приложение в соответствии хибернэйт? Почему в хибернэйт SessionFactory а в jpa Entity Manager если все должно соответствовать одной спецификации?
Что значит - "используя JPA потом можно сменить на другую реализацию? Jpa ведь не реализация... 
Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [JPA & HIBERNATE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/840365/204271)

Comment: Мой вопрос относится к конкретным деталям а не в общем что есть jpa и hibernate

Comment: Спецификация - это документ. В Hibernate есть SessionFactory потому, что реализация обязана воплощать описанный в спецификации минимум, но не обязана не воплощать что-либо сверх этого минимума. По этой же причине приложение можно построить в соответствии с JPA или Hibernate. В первом случае реализацию можно поменять просто изменив одну строку в конфигурации системы сборки, код править не придётся.

Comment: Т. Е говоря что строим в соответствии с JPA значит реализуем только минимум который требуется по JPA? И при этом естественно используется Hibernate или что то ещё для реализации?

Comment: Мы не реализуем, мы используем стандартизированный минимум. И нам без разницы код какой именно библиотеки вызывается, когда наш код вызывает `em.persist(someEntity)` например.

Comment: Ок.. Тогда используя например хибернэйт, и беря от туда только минимум который соответствует JPA(ничего сверху что может ещё сама хибернэйт предложить) это и будет значить построить в соответствии с JPA?

Comment: Да, ​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌верно.

Comment: Спасибо! Все понял