# Чем спецификация отличается от API или интерфейса?

Tags: java, интерфейс, спецификация

Возник вопрос: чем отличается спецификация от интерфейса или API? Все эти вещи по сути предоставляют чёткий контракт, которому должен соответствовать реализуемый класс. А в чём ещё различие?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие JPA и Hibernate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556989/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-jpa-%d0%b8-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с определения интерфейса из википедии:

> Интерфе́йс (от англ. interface) — граница между двумя функциональными объектами, требования к которой определяются стандартом[1]; совокупность средств, методов и правил взаимодействия (управления, контроля и т. д.) между элементами системы[2].

Для программной системы интерфейс - это граница между двумя компонентами. Для примера, возьмем класс. Его интерфейс - это то, что определяет его границу, как другие классы взаимодействуют с ним, т.е. набор его методов (включая их сигнатуры и то как эти методы себя ведут, как их вызывать, например, в каком порядке, какие допустимые параметры и т.д.).

Но очень часто, особенно когда речь идет о классе, то интерфейс употребляют в узком смысле, а именно, как сигнатуру всех функций, т.е. не включая сюда что именно делает метод, как он реагирует на входные параметры (то что еще называют контрактом).

API - это интерфейс к программной системе или компоненту, т.е. это синоним термина 'интерфейс', если мы говорим о программных системах. Ведь бывают и другие виды систем, а значит и интерфейсов. Например, мышь и клавиатура - это часть интерфейса между (непрограммными) системами 'человек' и 'компьютер'.

Спецификация - это документ который описывает требования. В общем случае спецификация может описывать необязательно интерфейсы. Например, она может описывать требования к производительности системы.

Но есть конечно и спецификация интерфейса, т.е. документ (не значит обязательно word или текстовый файл, а в более широком смысле - документация, которая может иметь разные форматы), который описывает интерфейс. Тут важно понимать что интерфейс может существует сам по себе. Т.е. если вы реализовали какой-то класс, то у него уже есть интерфейс, и этот класс можно использовать, но вот только как использовать может быть совсем не очевидно. Спецификация это как раз документация, которая эту проблему должна решить.

Answer (score 2):

Спецификация описывается в документации утверждённой заказчиком и вашей командой.
API И Интерфейс это уже реализация документации, которую вы утвердили с клиентом.

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс - это набор методов. Спецификация - это требования к реализации.

Для примера рассмотрим класс `java.lang.Object`.

В его интерфейс входят методы `getHashCode` и `equals`. В его спецификацию входят требования стабильности `getHashCode` (хеш-код объекта не должен изменяться самопроизвольно) и согласованности этих методов друг с другом (если `equals` показал `true`, то хеш-коды также обязаны совпадать) и т.п.

Comment: То есть по сути интерфейс описывает "что делать", а спецификация "как и что делать"? Плюс интерфейс требует реализовать конкретные методы и предоставляет их сигнатуру, а спецификация это нечто более абстрактное, вроде ТЗ или документа?

Comment: @Zhenyria ну да, только ТЗ всё же про другое